# vb.net procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

This seems so simple, but I can't resolve the error 
Procedure or function 'test' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied.
I have tried a dataadapter instead of the reader, tried the {call test (?)} syntax, and several variants on how to add the parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].test (@id int)
AS
 BEGIN 
    select * from tmptable where id=@id
 END


 Using conn = New OdbcConnection(connstring)
      conn.Open()
      Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("test", conn)
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 6)
      Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
      reader.Close()
      conn.Close()
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dropping the @ - so AddWithValue("id",6) instead. I usually explicitly create the parameter and add it to the collection, and when I do I drop the @ sign from the parameter name.

Also, I'll modify your code to look like how I usually use it and edit it into my post in a few minutes, if dropping the @ doesn't work you can try my style, maybe there are some subtle differences.

EDIT: Oops, my bad, I use the explicitly defined parameters with SQLcommands, not ODBC commands! You can try leaving out the @, but I don't have a working example I can share with you, sorry :-(

EDIT 2: OK, I don't have an example, but Microsoft has one that looks a lot more like how I call my stored procedures using SQLCommands, see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparametercollection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Basically, *I think* your code would look like

```
Using conn = New OdbcConnection(connstring)
  conn.Open()
  Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("{ call test(?) }", conn)
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  ' replace this with the following cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 6) '
  Dim ParamID As New OdbcParameter()
  ParamID.DbType = DbType.Int32
  ParamID.Value = 6
  cmd.Parameters.Add(ParamID)
  ' end replace '
  Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
  reader.Close()
  conn.Close()
End Using
```

And you should also be aware that some ODBC drivers are not good at getting recordsets back from stored procedures. I use SmallTalk to query DB2 through ODBC, and I can get a recordset back from a function, but not from a stored procedure. You may be encountering a similar limitation. What database are you using?

Comment: Thanks, your code works. I usually work in c# with SqlCommand, and found that in either environment calling "test" works with SqlCommand, but the syntax for an OdbcCommand has to be "{CALL test(?)}". The actual proc does a select and I haven't had any problems getting the results. This is with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for reporting back. We're trying to phase out ODBC in favor of SQL, but you never know when you'll have to go back and add a feature to old code :-)